# Is there any way to create iOS build from Windows VM other than networked Mac? (.Net MAUI)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-maui

hope you all are well.

I'm looking for one solution from the previous few weeks. I have not got any solution yet so posting my query here.

I'm working on Windows VM to create Xamarin.Forms application using .Net MAUI. I know that if we have Mac available in the same network then I can pair with that mac from my windows machine and test the iOS application on the simulator or I can create a build as well.

But in my case, I'm working on Windows VM provided by the client so I can not have Mac in the same network. As well MAUI is not yet available in MAC so my query is:

> ##### How we can create an iOS app bundle (IPA) from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a Mac at least in your network. There is no way around it. You can connect to it through the internet if you have to, but you will need it available to your Windows machine.

There is a solution called Hot Restart that allows you to connect a physical iOS device to your Windows machine and test that way. However, this only works for development purposes and you will need to have a paid Apple account for this to work. See Docs about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart).

If you want to create an IPA file that needs to go to the store, you will need to connect to a Mac.